# My UDP Server and Client work in Wifi local network but not working in 4G?

Tags: android, sockets

I have C# Client window application send image to android Server using UDP socket.
It work perfectly fine in local network wifi. When I use 3G/4G, it is not working.

For window side 4G connection, I use D-Link modern. My android side I use my phone 4G. I waste 1 week to solve this. Still can't find yet. What should I do to work in 3G/4G connection.

Comment: Aren't they needed to be in the same network for UDP to work?

Comment: I haven't test it out yet. Currently, I am testing with my home local network. both server and client are under my local network

Comment: What about 4G? Can you even use 4G inside your local network?

Comment: most mobile network can not handle incoming package. you need init the connection from mobile network side.

Comment: @JiangYD  So how other apps in market are using 4G connection?

Comment: @KaungSan sorry the `incoming package` means `init incoming package`, i.e. a connected-less udp or tcp SYN.